# How to Export First 100 product using dataflow profile

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, dataflow, importexport

How can i Export only first 100 products from magento using magento inbuilt data flow profile functionality. i want to export first products but there are 20000 products there on my store so i want to export products in bunch of 1000.Waiting for suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this **cannot be done with the stock standard Dataflow profile settings**, though you can achieve this using some external scripting to help out.

I would go the following route: (**tried & tested on a production environment**)

**Note that I wouldn't recommend doing so unless you are comfortable with SQL and accessing the database directly**.

This will have **no** detrimental effects if used correctly. The process will basically entail:

- Temporarily adding a SKU prefix to your first 100 products added,
- Running your Dataflow profile export using the sku prefix as an identifier, and then
- Removing the SKU prefix once you have your export
- Running a full cache flush & reindex

Create a script called `pre_export_sku_rename.php` in your Magento root directory:

```
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$connection_write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` ORDER BY `entity_id` ASC LIMIT 100";
$products = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
foreach ($products as $product){
$sql = 'UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `sku` =  CONCAT(?,`sku`) WHERE `entity_id` = ?';
    $connection_write->query($sql, array('temp_sku_rename', $product['entity_id']));
}
echo "done";
```

Create a script called `post_export_sku_rename.php` in your Magento root directory:

```
<?php
$mageFilename = '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$connection_write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` ORDER BY `entity_id` ASC LIMIT 100';
$products = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
foreach ($products as $product){
    $sku = $product['sku'];
    $sku = substr($sku, 15, strlen($sku));
    $sql = 'UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `sku` = ? WHERE `entity_id` = ?';
    $connection_write->query($sql, array($sku, $product['entity_id']));
}
echo "done";
```

Then open in a browser:

> {your_store_url}/pre_export_sku_rename.php

Make sure that you see the "done" message in your browser.

- Open `Catalog` → `Manage Products` and filter by `ID` ascending, also set the page view to 100. Make sure that your `pre_` script ran correctly and your SKUs now have the 'temp_sku_rename' prefix
- Then access System → Import/Export → Dataflow - Profiles → Add New Profile
- Set your profile up and under `Export Filters` set `SKU: (Starting with)` to temp_sku_rename (which you set up in the script)
- Run your profile

Once the profile has run successfully, open in your browser:

> {your_store_url}/post_export_sku_rename.php

Once again, make sure that you see the "done" message in your browser.

- Refresh your `Catalog` → `Manage Products` page to make sure that your `post_` script ran correctly and your SKUs no longer have the 'tem_sku_rename' prefix

You will now have exported the appropriate products successfully via Dataflow, please note though that you will want to correct the `Sku` value in your export before re-importing.

Also note, that after running the `post` script, it is adviseable that you do a full cache flush & a reindex on all indexes.